# Disable submit but make sure its re-enabled if back button is pressed

Tags: javascript, forms, onclick, onsubmit

I have a form that take a few seconds to submit.  I want to disable the submit button and display "Processing.."  I disable it for 5 seconds.  Problem is that the page the the form is being submitted to yay display an error and as the user to go back and fix the error.  When I click the back link the submit button remains disabled if it was successfully submitted before the 5 second timer re-enabled it.  Question is -  Is there a way to re-enable the submit button so if I have to go back a fix some form data it wont remain frozen?

Answer (score 3):

Your button inside form:

```
<button type="button" onclick="this.disabled=true; this.form.submit();" class="submit">Submit</button>
```

Using jquery load this script:

```
$(window).on('unload', function() {
    $('button.submit').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

For me, works like a charm.